# Codeigniter Routing Regex

Tags: regex, codeigniter, routes

I have a site with multiple languages. For my news page I have two rules to route the pagination variable to my controller. One for all the languages (en, ct, cs, kr), and one for the default language.

## Routes.php

```
$route['^(en|ct|cs|kr)/news/page/(:num)'] = 'news/index/$1';
$route['news/page/(:num)'] = 'news/index/$1';
```

## News controller

```
public function index($id) 
{
   echo $id; 
}
```

The routes are accessing the news controller, however the `$id` parameter isn't being passed to the `index()` method.

If I echo the `$id` it returns the language segment rather than the pagination variable I am expecting:

> mysite.com/en/news/page/2  // $id returns 'en'.
>   mysite.com/kr/news/page/2  // $id returns 'kr'.

It works when I write the routes out individually for each language:

> $route['en/news/page/(:num)'] = 'news/index/$1';

Am I going wrong somewhere with my regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because in your first rule, you're capturing 2 segments of the URL. The first one is the language (e.g. `en`), and the second one is the `id` (or page number). So, in your first rule you should instead use `$2` instead of `$1`.

```
$route['^(en|ct|cs|kr)/news/page/(:num)'] = 'news/index/$2';
```

Comment: Perfect! That does make sense. Thank you very much.