# Dynamic URL angular app

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess

I have built a SAAS using codeignighter + angular js. It is being used by multiple companies. Currently all of the code is placed in a folder under document root (/var/www/html/folder1) and site opens like www.mysite.com/folder1

As its a SAAS so users of various organizations/companies login to the app. so I want all users to see their organization/company name in the URL. I am trying to replace folder1 with dynamic names .

For example When a user from organization ABC login 
from www.mysite.com/folder1/#/login 
I want next url to be like
www.mysite.com/ABC/#/dashboard OR www.mysite.com/folder1/#/ABC/dashboard

Comment: there is nothing to do with folders hierarchy, you can "fix" the routing either in php or httaccess. which framework are you wroking with in php?

Comment: i am using codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in routing as following:

```
$route['.+/login'] = 'login';
```

this will redirect any request from form `/blabla/login` to `/login`
if you want to let only spcific url redirect to login you can do:

```
$route['ABC/login'] = 'login';
...
$route['XYZ/login'] = 'login';
```

for more information you can look [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700796/codeigniter-routing-regex)

Comment: Please suggest with angular js routing as I have routing in angualr js.